# Serialize DetachedCriteria with nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, serialization

I am trying to serialize a DetachedCriteria so I can save it in a database and reuse the same criteria at a later date. When I run the code below I get "NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor".

```
DetachedCriteria criteria1 = DetachedCriteria.For<SecurityObjectDTO>("so")
    .Add(Expression.Eq("ObjectCode", "1234"));

XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DetachedCriteria));
TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
s.Serialize(writer, criteria1);
writer.Close();
```

Is there any good way to serialize a DetachedCriteria?

Comment: So the user can create a criteria which I can then save in the database for later reuse.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into something similar before.  My first thought was to subclass `DetachedCriteria` so you could provide a default constructor yourself.  However, after digging through the `DetachedCriteria` class, I don't think this will work.  The reason is the `CriteriaImpl` class, used internally by `DetachedCriteria`, is also lacking a default constructor.

Looking at XmlSerializer, it doesn't look like it will work if your object doesn't have a default constructor.

I ran into this post, however:

[How do I serialize an NHibernate DetachedCriteria object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245985/how-do-i-serialize-an-nhibernate-detachedcriteria-object)

Based on that, this might work (I haven't tested it, however):

```
// Convert the DetachedCriteria to a byte array
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(ms, detachedCriteria);

// Serialize the byte array
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
s.Serialize(writer, ms.Buffer);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: As an aside, I'd think about finding an alternate way to represent your criteria.  If you could represent it as a string or XML value, then you could greatly simplify your serialization process.

Comment: What about deserializing to DetachedCriteria?