# How do I serialize an NHibernate DetachedCriteria object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, detachedcriteria

I am looking for a solution to persist NHibernate DetachedCriteria objects to a database.  I have tracked down the NHibernateUtil and the GetSerializable method, but I'm unsure how to use it to serialize a DetachedCriteria object.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792289/serialize-detachedcriteria-with-nhibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DetachedCriteria is serializable and because it is not connected to a session, it should be doable by just doing regular .net object serialization as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

If serialized to a binary format it could be persisted as byte-array to a binary blob field (NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob.SqlType).